# Polymorphic type in HDF5?

Tags: hdf5

I have a series of, say, *Event* objects, where *Event* is the base class of a hierarchy with different specializations (say, *HolidayEvent* and *SickDayEvent*). The base class has some fields (e.g. *date*, *employee*) and each specialization adds its own set of fields (e.g. a *HolidayEvent* would have *holidayName* and *SickDayEvent* would have *numDays*).

Is there any way to model polymorphic data elements such as these in HDF5 in a *nice* way? By *nice* I mean that the obvious alternative - creating a compound type with the *union* of all fields and a *type* discriminant - would probably waste a lot of storage space, especially when the specializations have many unique fields of different atomic types, and when the number of fields in specializations varies a lot, requiring the union to be as large as the largest number of fields in a specialization.

Answer (score 0):

In Hdf5 you can create arbitrary compound types. Hdf5 does not know whether they have a relation to each other. So I would suggest to create one Hdf5 type for each class type you have in the hierarchy.

[See here for more.](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/compound.html#def)

Answer (score 0):

This requirement is too advanced, and I don't think HDF5 can support this function directly.

One way I can come up with is using 2 HDF5 datasets to describe a logically polymorphic-type dataset.

First, you create a primary dataset, which covers all the fields of your super class, i.e., Event in your example. Moreover, this dataset also needs to maintain a **reference** to another auxiliary dataset, i.e., HolidayEvent/SickDavEvent in your example, which covers all the extended fields of a specific subclass. Therefore, you need to create as many compound datatypes as the classes you have here, but for each subclass' compound datatype, only the extended fields are included.

I think this is the only way if you don't want to waste any extra space but still make the super class polymorphic. Because the extended fields for different subclasses require different storage spaces, as you mentioned, it's highly inefficient to maintain all the unique fields in a single dataset.

Comment: BTW, I think the question is very interesting. Are you using HDF5 to describe a scientific dataset? Although I haven't met such a problem before, if this requirement is meaningful, then I think someone should implement and integrate it with the latest HDF5 release. Inspired by your question, I realize that there is a mismatch between HDF5 schema and XML schema. Currently HDF5 group simply use XML schema to validate an HDF5 file, because both describe a hierarchical organization. However, XML schema is object-oriented, but HDF5 is not.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up doing exactly this. I have in fact a dataset for the "base" class fields and N datasets for each of the N specializations. The "base" type includes an enum field declaring the specialization type and and integer field containing the index within that specialization's dataset.